# Can we use Entity Framework and ADO.NET together in the same project?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ado.net

ASP.NET Core .NET 6

- I would like to use Identity (using the default EF configuration) for my web app project
- At the same time, I also want to use ADO.NET or Dapper quite extensively for database queries
- Both EF and ADO.NET will use the same connection string

My questions:

- Will there be any problems such as clash in connections?

I tried ADO.NET in ASP.NET Core 6 and it works nicely, and used it to execute stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work fine.  An EF DbContext will open and close connections as needed.  Dapper/ADO.NET can open and close connections using the same connection string, and they will all share the same connection pool.

They can even share the *same* connection.  Either pass the DbConnection into the DbContext constructor, or let the DbContext manage the connection, and call

```
var con = this.Database.GetDbConnection();
if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    con.Open();
```

To get the DbConnection and ensure that it stays open for the lifetime of the DbContext.

Comment: Is the connection closed somehow? When I tried I recall having problems on the next request.